# Unable to open Cypress

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-modules, cypress

I am using ubuntu and I have integrated cypress into my project when I run following command.

```
 node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```

above command does nothing. I have attached a screenshot of my output[image]

Opening Cypress ... nothing happends after that.

Can anyone please help me on this?
Thanks

Comment: "cypress open" command launches a UI application. If you are running it on a remote machine (or docker) you will need to export your display. Maybe this will help https://superuser.com/questions/325630/how-can-i-export-display-from-a-linux-terminal-to-a-windows-pc

Answer (score 1):

Cypress takes time to execute the first time (is normal), I faced a similar issue before and I solved executing the installation and the execution of the command **cypress open** using the command prompt as administrator.